# Way to force load process in upper memory without recompiling?

Tags: windows, winapi

Working on fixing a pointer truncation issue caused by SetItemData/GetItemData on 64-bit machine and the pointer being pushed is bigger than a 32-bit integer. Problem is easy to fix once you know what it is (use INT_PTR or LONG_PTR and SetItemDataPtr/GetItemDataPtr), but is not always easy to duplicate the original problem.

The issue is the testing department wants to try and duplicate the problem with the old EXE before testing with the new EXE. We used to have a whiz tester who knew some trick to force a normal windows EXE to load in the upper address regions.

Do any of you smart people know a registry setting for the EXE image to force it to use the upper memory?

Comment: this is 64 bit exe and it have relocs ? without relocation it can not be moved. with relocation - set [`/HIGHENTROPYVA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/highentropyva?view=vs-2019) and [`/DYNAMICBASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dynamicbase?view=vs-2019). and run it on win10

Comment: Or use [/REBASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/rebase). Note that this (or RbMm's recommendations) can be done with `editbin.exe` or other tools that can modify the PE file.

Comment: Unlikely that your executable will have relocations.